# Is there any difference between constructor function and prototype object when using inheritance?

Tags: javascript

Consider the following to JavaScript snippets:

```
function foo() {
  this.bar = function() { };
}

// or... (if we used an empty constructor function)

foo.prototype.bar = function() { };
```

What's the difference when I do this:

```
function baz() {
}

baz.prototype = new foo();
```

In both cases `baz` ends up having a member `bar` but what's the difference? Why would I do this in different places?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The difference is *where* in the prototype chain the property is located.

Assuming we have `f = new foo();` and `b = new baz()`. Then we have the following situations:

Definition of `foo` without using a prototype:

```
+-----------+     +---------------+
|     f     |     | foo.prototype |
| __proto__-+---->| constructor   |  
| bar       |     |               |
+-----------+     +---------------+
```

`bar` is a property of the object itself (`f.howOwnProperty('bar')` returns `true`).

If you assign the property to the prototype instead, the situation is:

```
+-----------+     +---------------+
|     f     |     | foo.prototype |
| __proto__-+---->| constructor   |  
|           |     | bar           |
+-----------+     +---------------+
```

`f` does not have its own property `bar`, but the property is **shared** with all other `foo` instances.

Similar for the second snippet, which results either in

```
+-----------+     +---------------+     +---------------+
|     b     |     | foo instance  |     | foo.prototype |
| __proto__-+---->| __proto__    -+---->| constructor   |  
|           |     | bar           |     |               |
+-----------+     +---------------+     +---------------+
```

or

```
+-----------+     +---------------+     +---------------+
|     b     |     | foo instance  |     | foo.prototype |
| __proto__-+---->| __proto__    -+---->| constructor   |  
|           |     |               |     | bar           |
+-----------+     +---------------+     +---------------+
```

---

**Why do you want to do this?**

It's mainly about structure and not wasting memory. You can add functions to an object in a constructor function:

```
function Foo() {
    this.bar = function() {};
}
```

but this also means that each instance of `Foo` has it's own function, that is, `f1.bar === f2.bar` is `false`, although both functions are doing the exact same thing.

Using the prototype gives you a clean way to separate properties common to all instances and instance-specific ones.

In the end, it is "just" *inheritance* which is one concept in software development (like aggregation) and can be used wherever it makes sense. Your second snippet basically means that a `baz` *is-a* `foo`, so a `baz` instance, in addition to its own properties, has the same properties as a `foo` instance (inherited).

Answer (score 1):

One big difference is that if you change properties of the prototype those changes will apply to all instances, including those that already exist, whereas if you change a property that was created in the constructor it will only change it for the instance you change it on.

Regarding what some of the other answers said about setting `bar` in the constructor resulting in each instance having its own copy of the function: that's true if you have a function expression inside the constructor as shown in the code in the question, but not true if you assign a function reference like this:

```
function myFunction() {}

function foo() {
   this.bar = myFunction;
}
```

In that case all instances will have a `bar` property that refers to the same function - but an individual instance could still have its `bar` property assigned to something else without affecting other instances.

Comment: True, though even when using a prototype, an instance can have its own `bar` property without affecting other instances.

Answer (score 0):

To add onto the existing answers:

Making a prototype function would allow changes to it to be inherited.
i.e if you write

```
function foo(){}
foo.prototype.bar = function(){return 1};
function baz(){}
baz.prototype = new foo();
new baz().bar(); //returns 1
foo.prototype.bar = function(){return 2};
new baz().bar(); //returns 2
```

However, putting it in the constructor would let other objects inheriting from it also "have" that function, but the function is not inherited.

```
function foo(){this.bar = function(){return 1};}
function baz(){}
baz.prototype = new foo();
new baz().bar(); //returns 1
foo.prototype.bar = function(){return 2};
new baz().bar(); //returns 1
```

Comment: So in example 2, it behaves like a protected function of an object. Shouldnt this be the behaviour we want? It is like in all other programming languages...

Answer (score -1):

I think I'm answering the right question here, otherwise let me know.

The difference is that using prototype results in only 1 instance.

So, for example, baz.bar in one instance is the same as baz.bar in another. They will share values within the 'foo' instance:

```
function foo() {
    var x = 0;
    this.bar = function() {};

    this.getVal = function() {
        return x;
    }

    this.setVal = function(val) {
        x = val;
    }
}

function baz() {}

baz.prototype = new foo();

var a = new baz(),
    b = new baz();

a.setVal("1234")
console.log(b.getVal()); // prints '1234'
```

http://jsfiddle.net/jonathon/7GtRD/

If `a` and `b` were directly calling 'foo', then they wouldn't be sharing the values within the `foo`. However, this is where it differs slightly between setting `this.bar` and using the prototype to create bar.

Using the prototype would create one instance of `bar`. So `a.bar` will be the same as `b.bar`. If you do it the other way, they will be two different functions (doing the same thing).